# LAN traffic encryption on Windows

Tags: windows, security, networking, encryption, network-programming

I'm working on a study project and need to create a software which should encrypt LAN traffic between computers with Windows. So I need to capture, encrypt and resend all outbound traffic, and capture and decrypt all inbound traffic.
Currently I see two way to do it:
1) IP over UDP. I need encrypt IP packets and send them through UDP link, receive them and decrypt.
2) Encrypt payload of IP packets and decrypt it on another side.

I actually don't know how to do it better and where to start. All suggestions/examples will be helpful.

Comment: The simplest case would be using a vpn

Comment: @rekire, I can't use a vpn because it's a study project. It should be simple and show the concept.

Comment: VPNs can be easy to use some examples are hamachi or teamviewer, but I guess you need to program yourself depending on your programming language use a SSL/TLS library.

Comment: If you really need to __tunnel__ IP a SSL/TLS library is like using an electric screwdriver for driving nails...

Comment: @Kimvais depending on OP's task SSL/TLS can be used for tunneling -- see STunnel software.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp yes - of course it **can** be used, but using an *application* layer encapsulation on *Internet* layer is a bit silly. Technically you *can* also encapsulate ethernet frames in HTTPS...

Comment: @Kimvais and that makes perfect sense in restricted environments with firewalls/NATs or other limitations.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp yes, it *might* make sense if there are some imposed constraints but in general it does not solve *any* problem that UDP encapsulated ESP does not solve. At most it provides a *workaround* to a separate problem that is not described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you really only need to encrypt the traffic you can simply install a "manually keyed" IPSec SA. See [instructions at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

That being said, encryption is the *easy* part. Authenticating the peers and key agreements is the hard part.

Cryptography is hard to get right, so you definitely want do not want to invent a probably insecure wheel, but opt for a peer-reviewed standard solution, such as the [Internet Key Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5996) protocol. There is an (unfortunately discontinued) [internet draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kivinen-ipsecme-ikev2-minimal-01) of a minimal IKE implementation.

Please note that it is perfectly OK to use IKEv2 as the key agreement / authentication protocol for *any* application - not just for ESP. But if you need to encapsulate ALL IP, Encapsulating Security Payload in tunnel mode is your friend, and the lucky thing here is that *ANY* OS that is IPv6 compliant **MUST** implement it, so using ESP is in practice just a matter of installing the key material to your OS kernel's IP stack.

In case you need code samples, I have made a [minimal proof-of-concept level implementation of an initiating end](https://github.com/kimvais/ike) of an IKEv2 peer in Python. A Perl implementation doing the same can be found from [these IETF proceedings slides](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/80/slides/lwig-2.pdf)